# Migrating GCM to an existing Firebase project to use FCM while maintaining backward compatibility

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

am finally moving over to FCM from GCM. However, due to already having an existing firebase project, I did not import my GCM project directly over. Am currently stumped by this additional steps document by google:

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-firebase-project

I am not clear as to what step 2 - 4 means. I'm worried that since I did not import my GCM project over, I'm not able to support push notifications on older clients, especially with services like Intercom

Comment: You can have multiple Firebase projects, so did you consider importing your existing GCM project into Firebase now?

Comment: I'd imagine that would be my last resort. I currently have the existing firebase project as I migrated from fabric crashlytics to firebase crashlytics. But if it's really come to that, I think I'll import the existing project over and maybe try to migrate the data again into the newly imported project.

I'm just seeing if there is a way to link my existing firebase project with the old GCM one without abandoning my existing firebase one.

Comment: @kevinmkt Did you found a way to do so?